# My scrolling is not working in samsung android Mobile but works fine in all browsers and devices?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I am working on an application in which i have div as shown below

**HTML:**

```
<div id="commentDiv">
```

**CSS:**

```
#commentDiv {height: 458px; overflow: auto;}
```

In this div, comments are being populated from service. but the scrolling of div does not work in `android` though its working fine in all browsers and other devices like iPhone and iPad.

can any body solve this problem please its urgent.

Comment: We are going to need more information including example code. Also, mark previous questions as answered.

Comment: It's obvious that the comments are the problem. Replace them with better, more obedient comments.

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER: Try adding a `height` property in your css.

Comment: @Mudassir height property spoil my browser display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't. 
The Android browser does not support scrolling of elements other than `body`. 
In other words: `overflow: auto` isn't supported.

This has been filed as a bug a few years ago and it still isn't fixed.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6864&q=scroll%20android%20inner&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

or

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2118&q=scroll%20android%20inner&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

It works in alternative browsers, like Firefox mobile, though.

Comment: it would be great if you can add the link to issue report.

Comment: @WarrenFaith I didn't find the one I remember (it had like 50 comments of people complaining), I added another one. Edit: Oh it's here http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2118&q=scroll%20android%20inner&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER That is the default one, the one for the whole window. You don't need to do anything special for that.

Comment: so how can i achieve scrolling in android i remove overflow now what to do next???? i still cant scroll in android.

Comment: If the div is now extending to show all comments, because you removed the `height` and the `overflow` properties, the whole window should now be scrollable. If it isn't, I'd have to see the site or more details to tell why it's not working.

Comment: Yes, I can see whole comments now but the problem is that the requirement is the scrollbar and scroll which can only be achieved when div overflow is auto and second issue is that my browser's and other device data looks odd now just only because of this android issue.